# Show WPF ScrollViewer Vertical scroll bar on right always

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using ScrollViewer to show a long list of items and i use the below xaml structure

```
<Grid Background="#bdbec0">
    <Grid Name="scroll_Area">
        <Grid  Background="#bdbec0">
            <Grid>                   
                <ScrollViewer Name="scrollAreaPageView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"                                     
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">       
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                           //Long List of items here so either horizontal & vertical scrollbars are coming here based on content
                         </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The xaml shows the scrollViewer and long contents inside the scrollviewer. 
But when the height is more then the Vertical scrollbar appears but its in center only . So is any way to make the scrollbar to right side and keep content in center only ? Similarly the position of horizontal scrollbar on bottom always if width is more 
Sample pic attached here [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the scrollbar appear on the side of the window, you'll have to make the Scrollviewer stretch to the edge of the window. The scrollviewer's scroll bar is shown on the right edge (and bottom edge for horizontal scroll bar).

Do something like this:

```
<Grid Background="#bdbec0">
    <Grid Name="scroll_Area">
        <Grid  Background="#bdbec0">
            <Grid>                   
                <ScrollViewer Name="scrollAreaPageView"                                     
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">       
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                           //Long List of items here so either horizontal & vertical scrollbars are coming here based on content
                         </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I've made the Stackpanel center inside of the Scrollviewer and the Scrollviewer will now stretch fill it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the size of scroll viewer, Scroll viewer by default has the property to grow indefinitely if you dont specify the size, once you specify size and can content scroll property true, it will do the trick
Set can content scroll to true. To set the  VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignement of scrollbar.

```
<Grid Background="#bdbec0">
        <Grid Name="scroll_Area">
            <Grid  Background="#bdbec0">
                <Grid>                   
                    <ScrollViewer Name="scrollAreaPageView" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"                                     
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  CanContentScroll="True">       
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                               //Long List of items here so either horizontal & vertical scrollbars are coming here based on content
                             </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```